# CDD postdoc contract in France for more than 6 years

Tags: phd, postdocs, france, contract

I am an Indian citizen living in France. I did my PhD here, which lasted for 4.5 years. I was on a temporary contract (CDD type) for the PhD. After finishing the PhD, I was offered a postdoc position in France for another 4 years, again on a temporary CDD temporary contract. But due to a rule in France, I am not allowed to work on CDD contracts for more than 6 years.

I just wanted to ask if there is any way to circumvent this rule, and take the Postdoc position for 6 years. I read on some online forums that I can take a break between the PhD and postdoc contract for 4 months and then take the Postdoc position for 4 years. Is the same rule applicable for non-EU citizens also? Or am I supposed to take a break between the contracts for more than 4 months as a non EU citizen?

Comment: This seems more suited for Expatriates SE or Law SE.

Comment: Always worth asking if you can be employed on a CDI instead -- you never know!